# web project is not working on localhost

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat

I have a Java web project which has been developed in another machine and I imported it to in my `Eclipse`. Actually my Eclipse is `Spring Tool Suite Bundle`. After building my project successfully, I tried to access it using following URL.

```
http://localhost:8081/
```

It does not show anything and keeps loading. I have configured 8081 as my port number in `server.xml` file and I have given it in the `build.properties` file as well. It is like this

```
appserver.home=C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.11
tomcat.manager.url=http://localhost:8081/admin
```

server is working fine.
The project is originally built using `tomcat 6`, but I am using `tomcat 8`.

Could someone please help me to overcome this issue. Thank you all!

**server.xml** file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Server port="8080" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

    <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">

  <Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: post ur server.xml file. Make sure you don't put a path. Usually, if your application you called it as testproject; the tomcat server automatically sets its as localhost:8081/testproject

Comment: how are you deplying it to server?

Comment: @ravitadi I added the server.xml file

Comment: @Adi I use Ant to deploy it

Comment: are you getting any exception at server console when you hit this url?

Comment: no I get nothing in the server console. but I think problem is there since even before the project is deployed, I can see so many failures. however server get started up.